# AJAX request is not successful

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

The problem that we have is describing as follows. We have two different pages, the first one is called `profile.php` and the second one is called `save_button.php`. In the page `profile.php` I have this script which is written the following code in jQuery:

```
<script  >
$(function(){
    $("#save").bind('click', function(){
        document.getElementById('save').style.background='#F26522';
        document.getElementById('modify').style.background='#0083A9';
        $.ajax({
            url: 'save_button.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: { "callFunc1": "test"},
            success: function(response) { alert(response); }
        });
    })
});
</script>
```

In the body of `profile.php` page we have written this code, here we have two different buttons:

```
<body>
 <div class="button_container" >
  <input id="modify" type="button" class="buttons" value="Modify" onclick="changeText();" />
  <button id="save" class="buttons" >Save</button>
 </div> 
</body>
```

When we click the save button we want to execute the PHP code in another page, called `save_button.php`. Inside this page, `save_button.php`, we have written the following code:

```
<?php echo "test works"; ?>
```

What happens with us is that when we click the save button, in our page is not alerted the words "test works". Do you have any idea what to do in this page? Please, give us a quick feedback as this is a school project and we have to submit within the three next days. Many thanks.

Comment: Add an error handler to your ajax and log the arguments.

Comment: Did you debug this script. If first check that script save_button.php is called. You can make this in Chrome or in Firefox with Firebug

Comment: Any errors in the browser console when your press save?

Comment: what values are you sending to the save_button.php

Comment: When I press the save button nothing happen :( I stay in the same page and looks like the button does not call the save_button.php page.

Comment: Yasin, we send only the data as are shown in the first script. The save_button.php has only one line code, I mean only echo ("test works").

Comment: Your code  looks correct. I'll change `bind()` to `on()` but this wont fix anything. Also add `type='text/javascript'` into the `script` tag. What version of jQuey are you using? How do you load it?

Comment: ojovirtual, we added it but did not change anything. The version of jQuery i am using is in the link below:

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>, and i load the page using another script but this scirpt loads it correclty.

Comment: When you click the button, does the colour changes?

Comment: Thank you for your help. We used firebug as newman suggested us and there were some problems with javascript library included :)

Comment: we are posting for the first time. Can you tell us how to annonce our question solved?

Comment: You also need to load jQuery, not just jQuey-ui : `<script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>`

Comment: @loren why dont you send a value through ajax to the save_button.php page then retrieve the value and echo it and then you'll know whether the ajax request was completed or no